# Why does "\n" command not working on my output?

Tags: python

`\n` is not setting a new line for a string in my code. What is the problem?

```
class Account():
    
    def __init__(self, owner, balance = 0.0):
        self.owner = owner
        self. balance = balance
    
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        return (f'{amount} dollars has been deposited to your account. \nYou have {self.balance} dollars.') 
    
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount > self.balance:
            print(f"Insufficient balance. You have {self.balance} dollars." )
        else:
            self.balance -= amount
            print(f"Left balance is: {self.balance}" )
    def __str__(self):
        return (f"Account's holder: {self.owner}\nBalance: {self.balance}")
```

When I try to:

```
acct1 = Account('Jose',100)
acct1.deposit(50)
```

The output is :

```
'50 dollars has been deposited to your account. \nYou have 150 dollars.'
```

Comment: It works when you `print` it.

Comment: …and if you put the code in a file and run it, you won't see anything at all, because you don't actually `print` anything

Comment: If you run this as a script, and not in the interactive interpreter, you won't get *any* output.

Answer (score 1):

You're just returning the value. Try:

```py
acct1 = Account('Jose',100)
print(acct1.deposit(50))
```